# Turn string into string array for command-line arguments

Tags: c#, string, command-line-arguments, arrays

I have string with the following format:

```
"arg1" "arg2" "arg3" ... "argx"
```

I am going to use this string as the `string[]` for my program's command-line arguments.
How can I turn this string into a string array?

Comment: Use any available commandline parser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split the string on the original string.

if you need to remove the Quotation marks as well you could either loop through the resulting array and getting the substrings without the quotation marks

Alternatively you could use the [Regex.Split](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split) to do it in one go.

Comment: After a split you'll get corrupted arguments. Quotation marks are used to escape spaces. Quotation marks by themselves are escaped  with backslashes. And backslashes are escaped with backslashes. I'm not sure that's all. But your answer is a very dangerous simplification of a problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to implement all the escaping by yourself, especially in the way the CLR does for you.

So, you'd better look at CLR sources. [It mentions](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/479b1e654cd5a13bb1ce47288cf78776b858bced/src/utilcode/util.cpp#L2881) `CommandLineToArgvW` api which has a [nice documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx).

But we're C# guys and must [search this function signature here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/CommandLineToArgvW.html). Luckily, it has a good sample (my styling):

```
internal static class CmdLineToArgvW
{
    public static string[] SplitArgs(string unsplitArgumentLine)
    {
        int numberOfArgs;
        var ptrToSplitArgs = CommandLineToArgvW(unsplitArgumentLine, out numberOfArgs);
        // CommandLineToArgvW returns NULL upon failure.
        if (ptrToSplitArgs == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ArgumentException("Unable to split argument.", new Win32Exception());
        // Make sure the memory ptrToSplitArgs to is freed, even upon failure.
        try
        {
            var splitArgs = new string[numberOfArgs];
            // ptrToSplitArgs is an array of pointers to null terminated Unicode strings.
            // Copy each of these strings into our split argument array.
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfArgs; i++)
                splitArgs[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(
                    Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptrToSplitArgs, i * IntPtr.Size));
            return splitArgs;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Free memory obtained by CommandLineToArgW.
            LocalFree(ptrToSplitArgs);
        }
    }
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine,
        out int pNumArgs);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);
}
```

**PS.** Note, that executable name should be the first argument in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft now ships the `System.CommandLine` package for ***command line parsing**, invocation, and rendering of terminal output* (as stated on the GitHub page).

- NuGet page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine
- GitHub page: https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api

The package contains class `CommandLineStringSplitter` in the namespace `System.CommandLine.Parsing`, which provides a *singleton instance* and a **split method** with the following *signature*:

- `IEnumerable<string> Split(string commandLine)`

Here is an example of how to use the class `CommandLineStringSplitter` for reading a **line from standard input** and turning it into a classical `args` array:

```cs
using System.CommandLine.Parsing

// Step 1: Obtain the string splitter instance
var stringSplitter = CommandLineStringSplitter.Instance;

// Step 2: Read string from standard input
var commandLine = Console.ReadLine();

// Step 3: Parse command line using string splitter
var argsAsEnumerable = stringSplitter.Split(commandLine);

// Step 4: Convert enumerable into classical args array
var argsAsArray = argsAsEnumerable.ToArray();
```

I hope that was helpful! ‍